# why is htop command displaying a black screen

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, linux-kernel, windows-subsystem-for-linux

first I am new on linux, I was trying this windows `wsl` while following a tutorial, enabled it and downloaded ubuntu... like  everything works fine. but when I tried to run `htop` it is just returning a black frozen screen. I did `strace htop 2> strace_log.txt` and [this is the result](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CYqEOnPmELt4-J7RiJ8d9DPT1r6JQyeR) but I have no Idea what's happening can someone please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug caused by an incompatible glibc call involving CLOCK_REALTIME in WSL.

From [bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/htop/+bug/1871129](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/htop/+bug/1871129):

> The issue is happening because WSL is currently not POSIX compliant and any call to glibc that uses CLOCK_REALTIME will fail with EINVAL (-1) (such as clock_gettime() or clock_nanosleep()). It is likely that a glibc change has made this to appear (instead of the htop different version).

Related:

- [[WSL1] [glibc] sleep: cannot read realtime clock: Invalid argument #4898](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4898)

Answer (score 2):

IN short, DO USE UBUNTU 20.04 if you are using WSL1
USe 18.04 instead